# AMD driver 13.4 error in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, ati

i'm using ubuntu 12.04 and amd 6470M (laptop), i install lastest amd driver on my ubuntu (amd 13.4) but i can't decrease or increase display bridgness, i check in detail (on system setting) and i see the grapic is "unknown". anybody can help me? (laptop ASUS A44 Core i3-2330M AMD Radeon 6470M)

Comment: Usually, display brightness control is not related to graphics drivers,  but requires a driver on its own, which is specific to the laptop model. Please update your question to include the brand and model of your laptop.

Comment: i use amd 13.1 driver version and brightness control in my laptop is working fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in a terminal:

```
sudo amdconfig --initial
```

after installing the amd drivers.

Comment: thanks for the answer,,, :) but ist still not working for me :( i think i need link for download amd 13.1 driver for linux, :) thanks